# How to get city name from ion-input field in ionic 3?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

Here I want to have only city name how simply I can get, I followed some blogs but kind of confused.

my html

```
<ion-input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="default.city"></ion-input>
```

I am expecting something like

```
this.cityName = somefunction(inputText) {
 ...
 return city; 
}
```

I am looking for some ionic cordova plugin to autocomplete the typed location and list down the possible location and select one of them.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you want to do. What is the relationship between the ion input and this function ?

Comment: I just want to get city name with auto search when ever I type something in input field. @RanikaNisal

Comment: Is this list of places a list you provide. Or do you wish to use some geolocation

Comment: @RanikaNisal I want to use some geolacation

Answer (score 1):

Depending on when you wish to show you autosearch results you can bind it to an event

```
<ion-input  type="text" [(ngModel)]="default.city" (ionBlur)="someFunction()"></ion-input>
```

If you wish the autosearch results to come after he clicks out of the input box

you could use

```
 (ionChange)="someFunction()" or  (input)="someFunction()"
```

also if you need to

For Reverse geocoding you could use the geocoder plugin 
https://github.com/sebastianbaar/cordova-plugin-nativegeocoder plugin

```
somefunction(inputText) {
 this.nativeGeocoder.forwardGeocode('Berlin', options)
  .then((coordinates: NativeGeocoderForwardResult[]) => {
      this.autosearchresult = coordinates[0] // If you want one
 })
.catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
}
```

and display it on the somwhere in the dom

```
<div (click)="completeauto()" *ngIf="showAutosearch">{{autosearchresult}}</div>
```

Keep in mind that you will also need some method to remove the search results and set the searchbar to the clicked value. If the user clicks on it.

Additionally if you have a Google Cloud Account you can activate the Google Places API which is more Robust than the Ionic Native version but you would require a credit card enabled account for it.

MapBox API also provides geocoding but I am not all that familiar with it.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer I include more detail in my question please read it again :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Array of Object City `cities`, you can filter it by the name of the city in the following way

```
searchCityByName(searchText: any) {
    const length = searchText.length;
    console.log('filtering');
    console.log(length);
    if (length > 0) {
      this.cities= this.cities.filter(city=> {
        return city.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
      });
    } 
  }
```